# Scrolling div to top when toggled(closed or reopened)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div:

```
<div id="divPreObservation" style="overflow:auto;" >
-----------Large amount of text to scroll----------------
</div>
```

I have kept scroll bar for this div to scroll this text.

I have written a toggle method to toggle the div on button click (show and hide) as follows:

```
function toggledivPreObservation() {

        $('#divPreObservation').toggle();

    }
```

My issue is:

If i scoll the div to bottom and then close the div(by calling toggledivPreObservation()) ,
then next time again when i reopen it div scroll is at the bottom of div (i.e. user see text at bottom of div and again he has to scoll to top for reading)

For this i addded:

```
$('#divPreObservation').scrollTop(200);
```

in toggledivPreObservation().

But its not working.

What can be the issue?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown good joke :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wait until toggle animation ends and then call the scrollTop

```
$('#divPreObservation').toggle(function() {
   $('#divPreObservation').scrollTop(200);
});
```

before the animation end the style and position is not actually the same as you left.